# Whats wrong with telegram auth?

Tags: node.js, typescript, authentication, nestjs, telegram

Whats wrong? why hash and calculated hash not same?
in my opinion, everything is taken 1 in 1 from the documentation, I also checked with other people's code, and their logic is very similar to mine. Where is the error?

```
import * as crypto from 'crypto';
import { TelegramAuthBody } from './types';
import * as process from 'process';

export const TelegramValidator = (payload: TelegramAuthBody) => {
  const { hash, ...data } = payload;

  const secret = crypto
    .createHash('sha256')
    .update(process.env.TELEGRAM_BOT_TOKEN)
    .digest('hex');

  console.log(secret);
  const dataCheckString = Object.keys(data)
    .filter((key) => String(data[key]).length > 0)
    .map((key) => `${key}=${data[key]}`)
    .sort()
    .join('\n');
  console.log(dataCheckString);

  const hmac = crypto
    .createHmac('sha256', secret)
    .update(dataCheckString)
    .digest('hex');

  console.log(hmac); //90d1fbd25ac2c780030bf498d7cf1eeec33a5de801c59ba29cfdc95ca6973a14
  console.log(hash); //64dbbc3f87cf805ce918d7ca8356e9ca6243cc948fbe4d70b475a3c7287ae1e5

  return hmac === hash;
};
```

I try to swap secret and dataCheckString, but 0 effect.